# Python Logger not working

Tags: python, logging

I try to use logging in Python to write some log, but strangely, only the `error` will be logged, the `info` will be ignored no matter whichn level I set.

code:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('./logtest.log', maxBytes=10240, backupCount=5)
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)#no matter what level I set here
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.info('INFO')
    logger.error('ERROR')
```

The result is:

```
2014-01-14 11:47:38,990 - root - ERROR - ERROR
```

According to http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging-levels

The `INFO` should be logged too.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem is that the *logger's* level is still set to the default. So the logger discards the message before it even gets to the handlers. The fact that the handler would have accepted the message if it received it doesn't matter, because it never receives it.

So, just add this:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) explain, the logger's default level is `NOTSET`, which means it checks with its parent, which is the root, which has a default of `WARNING`.

And you can probably leave the handler at its default of `NOTSET`, which means it defers to the logger's filtering.

Comment: ...but the question sets it to `logging.DEFAULT`

Comment: This is not a solution, I might have different handlers and each one with different levels of logging. For example having a file_handler and a console_handler. Like defined in this article: https://realpython.com/python-logging/ , and not working.

Comment: I have done what the OP has done, but I also set the level and it still wouldn't log :/

Answer (score 15):

I got a logger using `logging.getLogger(__name__)`. I tried setting the log level to `logging.INFO` as mentioned in other answers, but that didn't work.

A quick check on both the created logger and its parent (root) logger showed it did not have any handlers (using `hasHandler()`). The documentation states that the handler should've been created upon first call to any of logging functions `debug, info` etc.,

> The functions debug(), info(), warning(), error() and critical() will
> call basicConfig() automatically if no handlers are defined for the
> root logger.

But it did not. All I had to do was call `basicConfig()` manually.

**Solution:**

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()  # Add logging level here if you plan on using logging.info() instead of my_logger as below.

my_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
my_logger .setLevel(logging.INFO)

my_logger .info("Hi")
```

```
INFO:__main__:Hi
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you might have to set the correct threshold.

```
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```