# How to set logging level in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following complete python (3.8.5) code example

```
import logging
L = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def main():
    L.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    L.warning("This is warn")
    L.info("This is info")
    L.debug("This is debug")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which should print out all three phrases, but only prints the first one (for warning).

How to circumvent this bug?

Comment: You need [`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109355/logging-setlevel-is-being-ignored

Comment: So https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105753/python-logger-not-working is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python logging root logger does not show info even if I set the level to INFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700371/python-logging-root-logger-does-not-show-info-even-if-i-set-the-level-to-info)

Comment: As per the question you were pointed to, you're required to define a handler. `BasicConfig` is a quick way to do that. The question you referred to asking if it's wrong includes several extra steps that you haven't done, including defining a handler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should switch the `L.setLevel` to `logging.basicConfig(level=...)`

e.g.:

```py
def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    L.warning("This is warn")
    L.info("This is info")
    L.debug("This is debug")
```

The method you used, sets the logging level for this logger specifically, meaning the specific logger won't actually do anything when logging on lower leverls - it has nothing to do with the logging level of the process and printing. Using `logging.basicConfig` you config the process' logging level, so even if you have multiple loggers this level will determine which logging messages come out of the process.

Comment: So it is a bug in python?

Comment: No, it's intentional, I can't really explain why they chose this path, but this is how it works. The best practice is to go with something like `logging.basicConfig(level=os.environ[...])` and take the logging level of the process from some environment variable

Comment: Then the method `setLevel` is not needed. It is a bug.

Comment: An interface that you misunderstood isn't the same as an interface with a bug.

Comment: Then I still misunderstand it

Comment: Especially the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: @Alex Try reading this: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow. There's the level of the logger and the level of the handler. You don't have a handler, so it defaults to the root with level of WARNING. That's also partially explained in that other post you linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21105825/2745495

Comment: According to the official documentation my way should work. I will create a python bug report

Comment: I don't think it's that difficult to understand: `Note that the root logger is created with level WARNING.`

Answer (score 3):

Use `logging.basicConfig`

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
L = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def main():
    L.warning("This is warn")
    L.info("This is info")
    L.debug("This is debug")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: So this is a bug in python?